# Flutter Project Can Not Run

Tags: flutter, dart

I make a flutter project. Previously i run it successfully without any error. But after some month when i try to run it then it shows the following error.

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\engrj\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\url_launcher_android-6.2.2\android\build.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':url_launcher_android'.
> Could not find method buildFeatures() for arguments [build_d32s1seyrxknqmyikjbawoo1l$_run_closure2$_closure5@73c0d2c0] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 483

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':url_launcher_android'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
   > compileSdkVersion is not specified.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Please suggest me a way to overcome this error and run the project.

Comment: try to upgrade packages with this command in project terminal **flutter pub upgrade**

Comment: try flutter clean > flutter pub get > flutter run